# Unable to recieve email from Google apps for domains

Tags: email, g-suite

I have read the FAQs and checked for similar issues: YES
My site's URL (web address) is: www.thesportslist.co.uk
Description (including timeline of any changes made):

1. My domain was registered by a 3rd party who pointed at everydns.net nameservers
2. I entered the following A record [www.thesportslist.co.uk    A    88.80.197.187    3600] in the everydns.net control panel
3. In IIS6 website tab, I have set up the IP, TCP & host header value for the above IP on ports 80 & 85 with www.thesportslist.co.uk and thesportslist.co.uk
4. I have verified my account with Goole Apps for domains
5. I can send email from Google mail but I cannot recieve mail, when I try to send mail to the domain account I got the following error:

---

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipients has been delayed.

```
   admin@thesportslist.co.uk
```

---

Reporting-MTA: dns;col0-omc1-s3.col0.hotmail.com
Received-From-MTA: dns;COL114-DS19
Arrival-Date: Tue, 28 Sep 2010 16:46:24 -0700

Final-Recipient: rfc822;admin@thesportslist.co.uk
Action: delayed
Status: 4.4.7
Will-Retry-Until: Thu, 30 Sep 2010 16:45:38 -0700

---

I am new to all this domain malarky so any help would be really appreciated (I'll owe you a pint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `MX` records for your domain, following [Google's very good instructions](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33352).

---

No, you didn't.  There are no publicly visible MX records for your domain, which is why you're having problems:

```
thesportslist.co.uk         IN  NS  ns1.everydns.net        86400s  (1.00:00:00)
thesportslist.co.uk         IN  NS  ns2.everydns.net        86400s  (1.00:00:00)
thesportslist.co.uk         IN  NS  ns3.everydns.net            86400s  (1.00:00:00)
thesportslist.co.uk         IN  NS  ns4.everydns.net            86400s  (1.00:00:00)
thesportslist.co.uk         IN  A   88.80.197.187               3600s   (01:00:00)
187.197.80.88.in-addr.arpa   IN  PTR    3244.virtual.yourshelter.net    0s  (00:00:00)
```

You need to create those MX records.

---

EveryDNS's DNS servers don't show any MX records for the domain.  They do show them for the website, which is your problem.  Try removing the MX records for `www.thesportslist.co.uk` and re-creating them for the domain itself - `thesportslist.co.uk`.

Comment: I have already added MX records and the instruction were good, but I still can't recieve mail.

Comment: Thanks that is what done it.  When it said fully qualified domain I thought I needed the www

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.... yay for a pint!

I did a quick dig (DNS lookup) against Google DNS servers for MX records on your zone... it did not have see any results... meaning you don't have any MX records configured (or they're missing somewhere).

```
root@mybxnotyrs:~# dig thesportslist.co.uk mx 8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R1 <<>> thesportslist.co.uk mx 8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15133
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;thesportslist.co.uk.       IN  MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
thesportslist.co.uk.    282 IN  SOA ns1.everydns.net. hostmaster.thesportslist.co.uk. 1285791007 3600 900 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.2.4.52#53(10.2.4.52)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 29 13:57:36 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 14282
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;8.8.8.8.           IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           522 IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2010092900 1800 900 604800 822

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.2.4.52#53(10.2.4.52)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 29 13:57:36 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

How did you 'add the MX records'?... in bind, you need to trigger a SOA transfer by modifying the serial number manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added the MX recordsvia everydns.net's control panel.  Would it be anything to do with the fact that someone else is in charge of the domain and have pointed at the nameservers for everydns.net?

Pint is nearly yours :)